# Seting a value from UITextField

Tags: ios

So i have two `UITextField`s one for reps and one for weight. these are then written to a custom class `BYFsets`. which is then written to a array in another custom class BYFWorkOut but for some reason i keep writing null to the array.

And i am add a pointer to null to the  array ''_workOut.sets'' ideas on why ? and how to fix it?

here is my code

```
-(IBAction)nextSet:(id)sender
{
    switch (setNumber.text.intValue) {
        case 1:
            setNumber.text=@"2";
            break;
        case 2:
            setNumber.text=@"3";
            break;
        case 3:
            setNumber.text=@"4";
            break;
        case 4:
            setNumber.text=@"5";
            break;
        case 5:
            setNumber.text=@"6";
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"she be default bro");
            setNumber.text=@"1";
            break;
    }


    BYFSets *set =[[BYFSets alloc] init];
    set.wieght = weight.text;
    set.reps = reps.text;

    [_workOut.sets addObject:set];
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any ponctuation would be appreciated in order to get your question...

Comment: I will remove my downvote for the effort...

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating the object properly, this...

```
BYFSets *set;
set.wieght = weight.text;
set.reps = reps.text;
```

should be... (UPDATED to show NSLog)

```
BYFSets *set = [[BYFSets alloc] init];
set.wieght = weight.text;
set.reps = reps.text;

//Now NSLog it
NSLog(@"value:%@",set);
```

Comment: What does `_workOuts` look like? especially the property sets. If you `NSLog` set  just before the add what does that display?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this code:

```
BYFSets *set;
set.wieght = weight.text;
```

You *declare* a BYFSets variable (`set`) but you do not give it any *value*. Hence it is nil. Hence everything connected with it is nil. `set.wieght` is merely a way of sending a message to nil; it has no effect. And when you log it, it is of course still nil.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid iv been up for awhile trying to get this app off the ground  thank you

Comment: You really should stop and learn Objective-C before you waste time banging around like this.

Comment: i fixed that but im still adding a null pointer to the array _workOut.sets(my last line of code)

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize `BYFSets`:

You need to do this

```
BYFSets * set = [[BYFSets alloc] init];
```